CellDingbat Background Issue
I've modified my stylesheet to illustrate some Wolfram code for my students. I created a CellDingbat and set the background to white, but for some reason, I still get gray coming through from the cell background. I want it to be white.

Here is my stylesheet code.
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
 CellFrame->{{1, 1}, {0, 1}},
 CellDingbat->StyleBox[RowBox[{"\[Wolf]","Check"}],RGBColor[1, 0, 0],Background->RGBColor[1,1,1]],
 WholeCellGroupOpener->False,
 CellMargins->{{112, 10}, {0, 7}},
 CellDingbatMargin->10,
 CellFrameColor->GrayLevel[0],
 TextAlignment->Left,
 Background->GrayLevel[0.85]]

I would like to keep the Gray background of the cell but not the celldingbat.  Any ideas?

You could FrameBox instead, which doesn't seem to have this unwanted margins around it.
CellDingbat -> 
 FrameBox[StyleBox["\[Wolf] Check", Red], Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White]


For some reason, I still get the gray background when I put your code in my stylesheet although it's not as pronounced.

@Bflat, I don't get any border in v14.1 on Windows ...
